# Error on system start 16.04: /usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart

Tags: 16.04, systemback

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 I see this error every time on system start:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2040) Fri Oct  7 08:03:55 2016: called for pid 2017, signal 6, core limit 0

ERROR: apport (pid 2040) Fri Oct  7 08:03:55 2016: executable: /usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart (command line "/usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart scheduler gtk+")

ERROR: apport (pid 2040) Fri Oct  7 08:03:55 2016: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 2040) Fri Oct  7 08:03:55 2016: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_lib_systemback_sbsustart.0.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
```

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to reinstall ubuntu.
if that doesn't work then your hardware might not be compatible for ubuntu. (I think the core processor)
try xubuntu

Comment: Hello @eliot-k ,  In theory hardware is compatible becase I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 with no problems.